# Google cloud: create instance template with empty disks

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How do I create an instance template that would create empty disks in the instances? It seems the source attribute is required for the disks while creating instance template.

```
- name: {{ TEMPLATE_NAME }}
  type: compute.v1.instanceTemplate
  properties:
    properties:
      machineType: {{ properties["machine_type"] }}
      canIpForward: False
      networkInterfaces:
      - network: "projects/mapreng-1/global/networks/{{ VPC }}"
        #No internet access if this is not specified
        accessConfigs:
        - name: External NAT
          type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
      disks:
      - deviceName: boot
        type: PERSISTENT
        boot: true
        autoDelete: true
        initializeParams:
          sourceImage: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{{ PROJECT }}/global/images/{{ IMAGE }}
      - deviceName: dev1
        type: SCRATCH
        autoDelete: true
        initializeParams:
          diskType: pd-ssd
          diskSizeGb: 20
```

This fails at runtime with " Source image must be specified"

Answer (score 0):

I think the point of instance templates is that they allow you to easily create many machines that all look the same when they boot by using disk images.  How are you thinking of using instances that don't actually boot because they don't have an OS on disk?

Comment: Not the boot disk. Boot disk I will specify like in my example above. It is additional disks that I want to add to my machine - e.g. device dev1 in my example above.

Comment: So can you create an instance with new disk, take an image from it, and then add it to this template?